# delphi hitting enter

Tags: delphi, enter, twebbrowser, onkeydown

How can I make an edit box so that when I hit enter with the cursor still in it. Then it goes to that website in the webbrowser which was in the edit box?

can anyone help me?

Comment: How much programming knowledge do you have so far?

Comment: What webbrowser? A TWebBrowser component in your form, or just using the system browser?

Answer (score 20):

You should use the `OnKeyPress` event instead of the `OnKeyDown` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    Key := #0; // prevent beeping
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Edit1.Text);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 "Should" is a strong word, but sure -- this will remove the beep (if you remove the syntax error so the code compiles!).

Comment: Hey, would you care to explain why `OnKeyPress` should be used rather than `OnKeyDown`?

Answer (score 6):

Drop a `TEdit` and a `TWebBrowser` on the form, and write an event handler to the edit control, namely `OnKeyDown`:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_RETURN:
      WebBrowser1.Navigate(Edit1.Text);
  end;
end;
```

To make it slightly more elegant, I would suggest

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_RETURN:
      begin
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(Edit1.Text);
        Edit1.SelectAll;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

## Update

If you rather would like the URL to open in the system's default browser, and not in a `TWebBrowser` on your form, replace `WebBrowser1.Navigate(Edit1.Text)` with

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(Edit1.Text), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

after you have added `ShellAPI` to your uses clause. But notice now that you *have* to be explicit with the protocol. For instance, `bbc.co.uk`  won't work, but `http://bbc.co.uk` will.